# show scope for each item in `git config --list`

Tags: git, git-bash

In windows bash it seems `git config --list` shows settings for multiple scopes but doesn't tell you which scope each is for.

I am trying to make sure I never have a CRLF problem again by setting `core.autocrlf` to false for everything.

`git config --list` gives me something like this:

```
$ git config --list
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=input         // <-- HERE
core.fscache=true
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
help.format=html
http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
rebase.autosquash=true
credential.helper=manager
gui.recentrepo=C:/Users/Buttle/PhpstormProjects/stuffs
gui.recentrepo=C:/Users/Buttle/PhpstormProjects/lolcatz
user.name=buttletime
user.email=Buttle@example.com
core.autocrlf=false                // <-- AND HERE
credential.helper=cache --timeout=3600
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true
core.hidedotfiles=dotGitOnly
remote.origin.url=https://github.com/buttletime/lolcatz.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
gui.wmstate=normal
gui.geometry=1385x655+182+182 420 192
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```

It seems like the 2nd one is probably local to my `lolcatz` project. But my global setting is also "false" when I check it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`git config --list --show-origin` gives the source file of the config setting.

From the FILES section of `man git-config`:

> If not set explicitly with --file, there are four files where git
>   config will search for configuration options:
>
> `$(prefix)/etc/gitconfig`: System-wide configuration file.
>
> `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config`: Second user-specific configuration file. If `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is not set or empty, `$HOME/.config/git/config` will be
>   used. Any single-valued variable set in this file will be
>              overwritten by whatever is in `~/.gitconfig`. It is a good idea not to create this file if you sometimes use older versions of
>   Git, as support for this file was added fairly recently.
>
> `~/.gitconfig`: User-specific configuration file. Also called "global" configuration file.
>
> `$GIT_DIR/config`: Repository specific configuration file.

Edit: Looks like the `--show-origin` flag was introduced in [v2.8](https://github.com/blog/2131-git-2-8-has-been-released)

Comment: This is a relatively new feature, you should note when it was introduced

Comment: This looks good for at least telling me which file to look in. But for using `git config` to change  value I need more info. I'm confused because when I try `git config --system` or replace system with "global" or "local", I don't see `core.autocrlf=input` anywhere, but I see it in the list, located in file `C:\\ProgramData/Git/config`. What scope is that?

Comment: The man page gives files for a *nix style filesystem, but I would guess that `C:\\ProgramData/Git/config` is the system-wide config file.

Comment: When I try to change a system setting, I can an error indicating that a different config file is the system-wide config: `$ git config --system core.autocrlf false
error: could not lock config file C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64/etc/gitconfig: Permission denied`

Comment: The file isn't writable from the shell you're running the command from. You need to run the command with administrator privileges, since it's a system file, that's easiest to do by running your shell with admin privileges and trying the command again.

Comment: Yes, but that that file doesn't correspond to system, global, or local scopes. The directive I want to change is in `C:\\ProgramData/Git/config". By using `--show-origin` with `--list` and a scope specifier, I can see that my global config file is at `C:/Users/Buttle/.gitconfig` and my system file is at `C:\\Program Files\\Git\\mingw64/etc/gitconfig`. Local is just in `git/config` relative to where I am. Is there some other scope than `system`, `global`, and `local`? Did git change where its system scope file is located since last version and is now using both for some reason? Is this a bug?

Comment: You could check your various files to see if any of them use `include` directives to bring in that other file.  If your goal is to set a particular `core.autocrlf` value, though, just set it in your personal global config (to make it your default), then unset it or set it as desired in each repository (to make it that repo's setting, or use your default).  You never *have* to modify a system file.

Comment: @torek so if I set it globally then new local configs should inherit it, right, rather than from any system config?

Comment: Yes: the general plan for every config entry is that the most local setting overrides.  There are some exceptions due to the underlying implementation but none of those should ever be set in any system-wide file (as in, that breaks everything :-) ).

Answer (score 3):

`git config --list --show-scope` gives the **scope** of the config setting - exactly what you want and a bit more convenient. This seems to have been introduced between versions 2.23 and 2.27 (in git for Windows)

Comment: The accepted answer gets the job done, but this answer works better, IMO